# Package name translation across different distros

Tags: package-management, distributions

I'm trying to write a general purpose script which at one point attempts to install certain packages on Linux systems. To handle the different package managers across various distros, I am using pacapt (https://github.com/icy/pacapt).

However, pacapt does not seem to perform package name translation. Packages have different naming conventions across distros, and hence I can't write a single command to install the packages on different types of systems. Is there any utility / webservice / list that I can use to translate package names from one distro to another?

Comment: It's worse than that! A package (e.g. `perl`) is not the same thing, as certain vendors who shall remain unnamed split the standard perl release up into various random packages. So you may also need to map a package on one system to groups of packages on another for the same set of files to be installed.

Comment: True. Though I just concede, I hadn't thought of that. Yet, if one were to maintain such a list, handling groups shouldn't be too hard

Comment: So how did you end up solving that problem, Darnir? I have it now :) and realized pacapt didnt solve it. Now, i'm tempted to have a config file that would have package names for every distro..of only the packages I use.

Comment: I didn't solve it. Instead like you said, I maintain a list of packages I want across the distros I care about. But a solution based on what Gilles said should be possible to write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different distributions have not only different package names, but also different ways of breaking packages down. I think your best bet is to define dependencies in terms of files rather than in terms of packages. For example, if you need perl, record that you want `/usr/bin/perl`, not `perl`.

Unfortunately, from a cursory look, pacapt doesn't seem to support querying which package provides a given file (`-Qo` only queries installed packages, not available packages). This would be a worthwhile feature to add. I'm not aware of any similar tool to do it; with some distributions, it might be difficult, as they don't all provide this information in a reasonable form (for example, on Debian, there's `apt-file`, but some derivatives don't provide the corresponding database). The [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta) lists the commands to use (`pkgfile` on Arch).

Comment: Gilles do you have a tip for me how to just translate this entire thing from Debian to Arch? I Don't know where to start from; `packman` won't do the same entirely: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489875/whats-the-advantage-of-mere-ansible-on-mere-shell-scripting-if-one-doesnt-use